# Can we use <main> instead of <div class="container"> in HTML5?

Tags: html, css, frontend, semantic-markup

I am new to HTML. I like to know it is good to use 
*mark semantic tag* 
instead of something like div class="main-content"? And also I like to know about where to semantic tags and div elements.

Comment: What's keeping you? I mean, can you explain why you think you can't use a <main> element? This sounds like it's primarily opinion based to be honest. Or are you asking about _when_ to use a <main> element?

Comment: There are also [schema markup](https://schema.org/docs/schemas.html) and [json-ld](https://json-ld.org/) - Learn about them too (But don't forget that the quality and relevance of the content itself is the most important thing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-main-element/#the-main-element), the `main` tag should be used only for content that is unique to that document.

> The `<main>` tag specifies the main content of a document.
>
> The content inside the `<main>` element should be unique to the
>   document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across
>   documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information,
>   site logos, and search forms.
>
> Note: There must not be more than one  element in a document.
>   The `<main>` element must NOT be a descendant of an `<article>`, `<aside>`,
>   `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>` element.

for more html5 tags you can visit [HTML5 Semantic Elements (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)